# How can I create a basic map in LeafLet?

Tags: leaflet

I´m starting to use Leaflet and there´s many things that I would like to know.

During my study I found this interesting video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wnsEYm9hF0o&list=PLGHe6Moaz52PUNP4DtIshALDogSURIlYB)
and I followed the instructions, using sublime text, but my result is different as you can see bellow. My map does not appear.

**My code is:**

[image]

**The result (From the video)**

[image]

**My result was:**

[image]

**HTML code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <style>
    #map {position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;not left: 0; right: 0;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id= "map"></div>
  <script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView ([0, 0], 1)
    l.tileLayer('https://api.maptiler.com/maps/streets/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=mji5GJMMFmiwn83UOmBb', {
      attribution:'<a href="https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/" target="_blank">&copy; MapTiler</a> <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors</a>',
    }).adsTo(map);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Compare `L.tileLayer` vs `l.tileLayer`.

Comment: You don't need to tag your editor unless your question is about it specifically.

Comment: ...and "addTo" vs "adsTo"

Answer (score 0):

In order to make your map visible, you have to make sure the map container has a defined height. For example, in CSS, you can do:

```css
#map { 
  min-height: 80vh;
}
```

Then, you have to set the map view to your chosen geographical coordinates and a zoom level:

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([latitude, longitude], zoom level);
```

Finally when you add the tile layer to the map, you made two typos, you must write:

- `L.tileLayer` instead of `l.tileLayer`
- `addTo` instead of `adsTo`.

It should work like that.